# How to perform correct calculation on very large number in .net

Tags: c#, .net

I am having problem in performing correct calculation in following as result is overflowing so function is not returning correct answer.

```
public static UInt64 findNwords(UInt64 nletters, UInt64 length)
{
    if (nletters == 1) return 1;

    UInt64 half1 =  nletters / 2;
    UInt64 half2 = nletters - half1;

    UInt64 loc0 = half1;
    UInt64 loc1 = half2;
    UInt64 curr = 1;

    for (UInt64 i = 1; i < length; i++)
    {
        curr = (loc0 + loc1);
        loc0 = loc1;
        loc1 = curr;
    }

    return (curr * half2) % 100000007;
}
```

Calling `findNwords(1000, 500)` should return `6109294`. In my case it's returning `19610514`. Please help.

Comment: You can use `BigInteger` if this is overflowing

Comment: Just debug it and watch whats happening.

Comment: @NeerPriv I have already done that.

Comment: @w.b I suppose it requires a library which I am not allowed to use.

Comment: @user4129542 - it's a standard .NET structure - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Your program is overflowing the 64-bit space at iteration 79. You can easily test this by encapsulating the `for`-loop with an `checked`-block:

```
checked
{
    for (UInt64 i = 1; i < length; i++)
    {
        curr = (loc0 + loc1);
        loc0 = loc1;
        loc1 = curr;
    }
}
```

This will throw an exception if the one value overflows during an operation. You can't do anything about this, besides changing your algorithm by either using lower values or using a `System.Numerics.BigInteger` instead of `UInt64`. The second solution requires you to add the `System.Numerics` assembly as reference. By doing this the algorithm returns the expected value of *6109294* for your example.

Comment: Using BigInteger is returning 61029892 for me.

Comment: Okay, almost... did not check this twice, perhaps it is because your loop starts at 1, not at 0? If the result is not correct, than your algorithm isn't. Since we do not know what you are trying to implement, it's hard to answer what the logical error is here.

Comment: Calling `findNwords(1234, 234)` should return `21604313`. I am not allowed to use references but the test case consists of larger values.

Comment: Outsourcing code into assemblies and referencing them is a good practice in programming, so why aren't you allowed to use references (`System.Numerics` is a standard .NET library so there's nothing wrong with referencing it)? Also, from how the question is asked, I think this is a homework task. Without knowing what you are trying to achieve or how the result should get calculated it is impossible to know where your problem is. Please provide more detail in your question; "correct" is a word that's relative and impossible to verify, if we do not know what it actually means in your case!

Comment: @user4129542, Your algorithm returns 98515968 when called 'findNwords(1234,234)'. You should verify your algorithm or share what you are trying to implement.